# Leaflet: Smooth lines between points without control points?

Tags: qgis, leaflet, line, smoothing, spline

**Goal**

I want to connect points using a polycurve or curved lines in Leaflet in a scalable way. If possible, without defining control points.

**Approach**

I'm using the [Leaflet.curve plugin](https://github.com/elfalem/Leaflet.curve) which offers quadratic and cubic bezier curves. I took a screenshot and created a jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/p1zx5k73/28/) of only a limited set of connected points. The js code is further below.

[image: Quadratic bezier curves between points using the Leaflet-curve plugin]

**Problem**

My approach is not scalable with the Leaflet-curve plugin since I need to create a control point for all inter-points connections each.

```
lng = Point_One[0] + 0.5 + ((Point_Two[0] - Point_One[0]) / 2)
lat = Point_One[1] + 0.5 + ((Point_Two[1] - Point_One[1]) / 2)
...
```

I can automate getting the mid-point between two points and its direction (+/-), but I don't know how to automate offsetting the control point. The length between points varies. In practice, I have hardcoded the size of the offset. If you look closely, you can see that the curves are not equally distributed between points which would also be nice.

**Questions**

1. Are there any good frameworks to draw smooth lines between points in
   Leaflet?

I have read about Raphael, but it no longer seems to be available(?).

2. Is there a way to optimize the way I use the Leaflet-curve plugin?

I assume I could have bigger/smaller offsets dependent on inter-points distance.

3. Are there any QGIS plugins to create splines/smooth lines *between points* (in a dataset) and export these as a geojson layer?

I have no experience with, but read about the Spline and CadTools Plugins.

```
var Mapnik = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
});

var mymap = L.map('mapid', {
    layers: [Mapnik]
}).setView([49.165804, 39.517246], 4);

var Warsaw = [52.233333, 21.016667];
var Brest = [52.133333, 23.666667];
var Moscow = [55.75, 37.616667];
var Yekaterinburg = [56.833333, 60.583333];

var curved_line = L.curve(['M', Warsaw,
    'Q', [Warsaw[0] + 0.5 + ((Brest[0] - Warsaw[0]) / 2), Warsaw[1] + 0.5 + ((Brest[1] - Warsaw[1]) / 2)],
    Brest,
    [Brest[0] - 3.5 + ((Moscow[0] - Brest[0]) / 2), Brest[1] - 3.5 + ((Moscow[1] - Brest[1]) / 2)],
    Moscow,
    [Moscow[0] + 3.5 + ((Yekaterinburg[0] - Moscow[0]) / 2), Moscow[1] + 3.5 + ((Yekaterinburg[1] - Moscow[1]) / 2)],
    Yekaterinburg,
      ], {
  fillColor: 'green',
  weight: 4,
  opacity: 1,
  color: 'green',
  fillOpacity: 1,
  lineCap: 'round'
});

var straight_line = L.curve(['M', Warsaw,
'L', Brest, Moscow, Yekaterinburg, {
    fillColor: 'blue',
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 0.5,
    color: 'blue',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    lineCap: 'round'
}]);

mymap.addLayer(straight_line);
mymap.addLayer(curved_line);
```

Comment: did you find an answer to your question? I would like to do the same thing.